# How to configure ZingChart width and height?

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I'm trying to use [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/). Trying to build gauge widget. Question is for those who worked with zingChart. How to configure width and height of space around chart. So here is what i'm saying about:

[image]

White container is a `div with 100% width` and height. All yellow space is `plotarea` of the zingChart, and in the center is gauge.

I want to cut all yellow space at the top and bottom around gauge. How to configure that?

Here is my chart config in react:

```
import React from 'react'
import './PlanGauge.sass'
import 'zingchart/es6'
import ZingChart from 'zingchart-react'
import WidgetTile from '../WidgetTile/WidgetTile'

function PlanGauge({ title }) {
  const widgetConfig = {
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 150000,
    currentValue: 100000,
  }

  const chartConfig = {
    type: 'gauge',
    'scale-r': {
      aperture: 180,
      values: `${widgetConfig.minValue}:${widgetConfig.maxValue}`,
      ring: {
        size: 12,
        'background-color': '#F2F4F6',
        tick: {
          visible: false,
        },
      },
      center: {
        visible: false,
      },
      tick: {
        visible: false,
      },
      item: {
        //Scale Label Styling
        visible: false,
      },
    },
    plot: {
      size: '100%',
    },
    series: [
      {
        values: [widgetConfig.currentValue],
        'background-color': '#000',
        'border-color': 'red',
        indicator: [4, 4, 0, 0, 0.9],
      },
    ],
    plotarea: {
      marginTop: 0,
      marginBottom: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
  }
  return (
    <WidgetTile title={title}>
      <ZingChart data={chartConfig} />
    </WidgetTile>
  )
}

export default PlanGauge
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set padding in the ZingChart configuration's plot object to control the area around it. The Plot object controllers the styling of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin in the ZingChart configuration.
plotarea: {
margin: '0 0 0 0',
},

It works for me.